# Displaying URL in a TextArea using JavaFX

Tags: javafx, textarea

I am creating a web browser using JavaFX class. I am storing the history of the browser in a file and displaying in on a TextArea. On clicking a URL a webpage should open.The problem is URL cannot be converted into a String. How do i display a URL inside a TextArea or is there any other container to display a URL? However, the same thing is possible if a JEditorPane is used (using javax.swing). Thanks in advance.

```
TextArea area=new TextArea();
String x="http://www.google.com";
URL url=new URL(x);
area.appendText(url);  // ERROR at this line. URL cannot be converted to a String
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/hyperlink.htm.

Comment: But then it does not display a hyperlink inside a TextArea right? i need a texts+url to be displayed. How is it possible without using TextArea?

Comment: Not possible with JavaFX AFAIK. There is an HTMLEditor, and the Webview that understand HTML. In your case you can either implement your View in HTML and display it in the Webview, or use a SwingNode to embed a JEditPane or whatever . http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html